# How to select multiple cells in a table view

Tags: ios

I have a table view with multiple cells. When I click on one of the cell it navigates to the next view controller, but my problem is that I cannot select multiple cells.
Could any one please help me on this issue, I want to select two or more cells with two finger tap.

Comment: are you using interface builder or doing it programmatically?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828171/didselectrowatindexpath-selecting-multiple-tableview-cell-accessorys  look at

Answer (score 1):

set by code if you set by programming

```
table.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;
```

and if you set in xib tick on allowsMultipleSelection

Answer (score 0):

If you are implementing the tableview programatically then the better way is to create a **custom cell** which will have **button** (and obviously other UI components that you need to show in the table view cell) which will **work as a checkbox** and assign **button.tag as indexPath.row** which will help you to select multiple rows.

Take a look here --
Below code will go into **cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
YourCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.button.tag = indexPath.row;
[cell.button addTarget:self action:@selector(multipleCheckAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
return cell;


-(void)multipleCheckAction:(UIButton *)sender { //sender.tag will be equal to indexPath.row }
```

Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

Just add button like checkbox and multiple choose like checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Since cells are being reused, you need to set the accessory mark to on or off for every cell in the table in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` table datasource method.

So the cell.accessoryType cell property should be specified in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and not the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` delegate method.

In the `didSelectRow`, just keep track of the selected rows in an array, and set the cells accessory mark to none or checkmark in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` depending on the array value.